# Request entity is too large with httppost

Tags: android, httpclient, loopj

I am sending string of json object of more than 1000 user profile records. And the server sends me this error:

```
 <head><title>413 Request Entity Too Large</title></head>
 <body bgcolor="white">
 <center><h1>413 Request Entity Too Large</h1></center>
 <hr><center>ngx_openresty/1.2.4.14</center>
 </body>
 </html>
```

I am using the loopj (http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) lib.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the sever's setting to let it accept larger request. otherwise you have to split your request into small species.

Comment: I cant split request because if the request is successful then server send me some data which is depend upon request and  i need to show that returned data on my UI so i can't do that. Please suggest me some another way.

Comment: If i make this post request from iPhone then it works perfectly upto for 1500 user profile records. but in case of android the server sends me the above error only for 120 user profile records...   Now ? what to do ???

Comment: on NGINX you open nginx.conf，and find http{} period，then set '
client_max_body_size 20m' and restart NGINX

Comment: have you logged the incoming request (on the SERVER) for both your iPhone and Android devices? sounds like there's a bit of cruft in your Android requests.